# Not able to build python3.4 from source (RHEL 6)

Tags: python, linux, rhel

I am trying to build and compile python3.4 from a source tarball on various RHEL servers (they are all supposed to be the same model of server). I have checked md5sum and they are all the same as the one on the Python website.

However, on some servers, when I compile python3.4 (./configure -> make -> make install), the server goes into an infinite loop during the "make" step. It keeps "checking for" various elements.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red Hat Software Collections is a relatively new offering to make fresh versions of Python, Ruby, etc. available for RHEL 6 and 7.  They are included with most RHEL subscriptions and they install along side the original/base versions that are part of RHEL. Python 3.4 is among the list.

To get started, go to http://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/overview/